# How can I remove mounted volumes from the list that are no longer attached?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, mount

I have a problem and I suspect that it might be a symptom of a hardware issue though I am hoping I'm wrong.

If I connect an external drive or mount a disk image it shows up in finder and I can see using the "Disk Utility.app" and it shows up using:

```
diskutil list
```

When I finished working with the drive or image I eject it an move on with my day unit a later point when I connect the drive/image again. The problem is, I now have two mounted versions of the same drive. Trying to open "Disk Utility.app" does not work as it endlessly keeps "Loading disks". There is nothing under /Volumes (so no mountpoint) however

```
diskutil list
```

Shows the duplicate disks still being connected?

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Backup2_GO              2.0 TB     disk2s2

/dev/disk5 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk5
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk5s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Backup2_GO              2.0 TB     disk5s2

/dev/disk6 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk6
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk6s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Backup2_GO              2.0 TB     disk6s2
```

These are all the one drive which is no longer connected at all. I cannot eject the drive from finder as it is not mounted, I cannot do anything using "Disk Utility.app" as it does not work in this state and I cannot remove the drives using diskutil

```
diskutil unmountDisk disk2
Unmount of all volumes on disk2 was successful
```

Though it really was not as all drive are still there and not unmounted at all.

What can I do here? A restart usually solves this however that gets to be really annoying quick.

I cannot open /dev in finder. I can see the content using the terminal though I am unable to remove the mountpoints, even using sudo.

Any suggestions regarding a solution or what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So I did a big "no-no" though it seems to have solved the issue. I found a solution to a related issue and without putting to much thought into it I just tried it. I know, stupid though it seems Time Machine might have been the problem(?). If the solution works I'll add it as an answer to the question though I will give it a few hours and mounts/unmounts before pulling the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

So, I had to revise the title/question as the solution to my problem was not an answer to the question posted originally.

As far as I know, there is no way to manually edit the list of attached volumes manually. However, I managed to prevent mounted volumes to become "permanently attached" by borrowing parts of a solution to a similar problem.

The problem seems to be "Time Machine" related, I cannot say for sure though it seems like the problems I described was observed after mounting an old backup drive to access other files. I read a description of a similar problem and thought I'd give it a try and so far it seems to have solved my issue.

1. Remove the disk from Time Machine's list of backup destination
   drives
2. Move/Rename or Remove the file "tmbootpicker.efi" from the drive's root
   directory
3. Move/Rename or Remove the file /var/db/volinfo.database
4. Restart
5. Mount you backup drive and re-add to Time Machine for future backups

After a slower than usual restart (sweating bullets) I was able to mount drives again, tested a backup, mounted and unmounted drives and so far, they are ejected properly and removed from the output of `diskutil list`. I have not observed any other unwanted effects so far.

This solved my problem (even if this was not the initial question) and I thought I'd post it here if someone else experience similar issues.